# Select the parent entity of a child with entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, entity-framework

I have a one-to-many relationship between each parent and their child entities.  When I perform a .Where statement to select certain child elements, how do I then select the parent entity also?

The parent object:

```
Class Parent
    Property Id As Integer
    Property ParentName As String
    Overridable Property Vehicles As ICollection(Of Vehicle)
End Class
```

The child objects:

```
Class Vehicle
    Property Id As Integer
    Property VehicleRegistration As String
End Class
```

I select the child entities I need with the following statement:

```
DbContext.Vehicles.Where(Function(m) m.VehicleRegistration.Contains(searchTerm)).ToList()
```

I need to be able to iterate through this list and select the parent of each child, or include the parent columns in the output so I can display in the MVC view.

Comment: `Vehicle` needs a property `ParentID` (I assume you must have that in your database in order to create the relationship)

Comment: yes the scaffolding created the database table with a Parent_Id field. I can select a parent explicitly and then iterate through the child entities using Parent.Vehicles fine so the relationship is defined.